# .Net 4.0 Redistributable - where can I find it?

Tags: .net, redistributable

I've been stuck using .Net 2.0 for the last few years and have only just had the opportunity to use VS2010 and .Net 4.

When Visual Studio 2005 is installed on a machine it provided the dot net redistributable package (dotnetfx.exe) at location C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\BootStrapper\Packages\dotnetfx\dotnetfx.exe.

I can't find a similar location for the .Net 4.0 package for VS 2010, does it give you one?  Or do you have to download it?  Or does it package it into a setup file if you create a setup project?

I am deploying to a closed network with no internet access, so I can't let the installer connect to a Microsoft site and download it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deploy as a setup project, as you mentioned, the user will be prompted automatically to download the version of .NET associated with your project -- that being if the OS they are on meets the right criteria.  You shouldn't need to worry about including any .NET redistributables, as the installer will handle it.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this earlier - I am deploying to a closed network with no internet access.

Comment: Ah -- never had that situation.  However here's a link that looks exactly like what you're trying to do:  http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/deploying-c-setup-exe-with-net-3-5-redistributable/  (I'm sure the same applies in 4.0)

Comment: Thanks George, that looks just like what I was after!  May I ask what google search term you used to find that?  I wasn't having any luck!

Comment: @Merlin .net setup project deploy .net redistributables

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what VS2010 install options you need to select to get the redistributable package, but you can download it from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263).

Answer (score 1):

[Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718) the Microsoft `.NET Framework 4` (Stand-alone Installer):